# rails admin can't locate rails_admin.scss.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

rails admin throw error then i'll try to enter on /admin

```
Errno::ENOENT in RailsAdmin::Main#dashboard 
No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /home/acer-as/work/vendor
  (in /home/acer-as/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@myproject/bundler/gems/rails_admin-f420baa7acad/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/rails_admin.scss.erb)
```

i installed everything like usual, and can't understand what is wrong with it
rails 4.1.0 (also try on 4.1.5)
ruby 2.1.1
P.S fi'll checked this path:  /home/acer-as/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@myproject/bundler/gems/rails_admin-f420baa7acad/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/rails_admin.scss.erb 
 file on right place, so it’s not missed

Comment: http://fromacoder.com/custom-rails_admin-css-and-or-javascript-for-rails-4/ it may be help you

Comment: thx, but allready solved